# Is there any difference between "suppose", "assume" and "let's say" in hypothetical questions?

Tags: difference

Could you tell me if there is any difference between *suppose*, *assume* and *let's say* in hypothetical questions? For example:

> **Suppose** you lost your job, what would you do?
>
> **Assume** you lost your job, what would you do?
>
> **Let's say** you lost your job, what would you do?

If they mean exactly the same, are all perfectly natural?

Comment: All of them are run-on sentences and hence are grammatically incorrect. However, apart from that, in essence they mean the same.

Comment: I would say '_Assuming_ you lost your job...' rather than 'assume'.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Could you tell me why are they run-on setences. What would you change?

Comment: Kate Bunting: Thanks for the comment! Is "assume" incorrect or is it what you would just say?